# Looking for a specific Harry time travel fanfic (answered)

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Starts off with Harry after Hogwarts entering his house with some fire whisky on Halloween (or the day before). He also is commenting on how he wishes that on this day that journalists leave him alone to mourn.

He then finds a joker card with his mail and no matter what he does to get rid of it, it will always come back again. He also has the three Deathly Hallows even though he threw the stone in the forest and left the Elder Wand in the headmaster's tomb.

He can’t seem to get rid of them and after he tries they return to him.

Sitting in one of the room he waits for midnight to start drinking and at twelve is sent back in time or to a different universe. He also got sorted in Hufflepuff I think. I think I read it on fanfiction.net.

Comment: This is super light on details. Is there _anything_ else you can remember? See if you can check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=Y96zWpDaMMrSgAbN5aOoCg&q=inurl%3Afanfiction.net+%22Harry+potter%22+AND+%22joker+card%22+-%22the+joker%22&oq=inurl%3Afanfiction.net+%22Harry+potter%22+AND+%22joker+card%22+-%22the+joker%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9406.15653.0.15759.13.13.0.0.0.0.135.774.12j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.5geZ_y3U4u0 - One of these, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry but no :,(

Comment: Instead of editing your question that it got answered (which shouldn’t be done, so please [edit] your question to remove the "(answered")), you can mark the answer that answered your question as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is C'est La Vie by Cywscross, it can be found [here](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3390668?view_full_work=true), though it was on fanfiction.net at one point, I think it no longer is.  I was recently looking for it myself, you see.

It does start with grumbling about reporters, and hyphenated names.  There is a joker card, which was literally fate's calling card (she's the one who sends him to a different universe, supposedly as compensation - a chance to start over, as it were).  That's the detail that makes me think this is the one.  If it helps, in the universe he goes to his counterpart has his family and is rather spoiled, the hyphen-name and prophecy belongs to Neville.

Comment: Yes! That the one ! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: @Itsme If this is correct, please mark it as correct by clicking the green tick mark next to the answer. Both you and Megha will get a reputation boost and any future visitors will be able to see much more readily that the correct fic has been found.